# How do I structure a threaded UDP server in D without pass-by-value?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, d, messaging, pass-by-value

I'm trying to construct a very basic threaded UDP server in D. Naturally, I'm bumping into some problems with the fact that objects (which are the primary construct type in `std.socket`) are strictly pass-by-reference by design.

This code's intent is to start up a listen socket on one port and a reply socket on another. The reply socket then just pulls from its message queue and sends.

```
void replySock() {
    UdpSocket reply_s;
    OutBuffer out_buf;

    // Create, bind our reply socket

    while (1) {
        receive(
            (ubyte[140] m, Address c) {
                // Print info about client address c
                // Print message m
                // Fill a new OutBuffer with our response
                reply_s.sendTo(out_buf.toBytes(), c);
            }
        );
    }
}

void main() {
    UdpSocket listen_s;
    ubyte[140] in_buf;

    // Create, bind our listen socket
    auto replyChild = spawn(&replySock);

    while(1) {
        // ...
        listen_s.receiveFrom(in_buf, client_addr);
        replyChild.send(in_buf, client_addr);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Naturally, D doesn't like the fact that `client_addr` is thread-local and can't be copied into `c`. Sharing it with a mutex lock is out of the picture, since `client_addr` changes with each message; `replySock()` referencing it each time it replies has obvious catastrophic downsides.

How can I pass that address idiomatically? Should I be structuring this basic server differently?

Comment: You don't need two sockets. That will only confuse clients, by giving a differenct port number for replies.

Comment: Edited: Nevermind, I realized the socket will of course be passed around by reference.

Comment: Blargh, why do so many people use threads like this? My view is you ought to avoid the use of threads wherever possible, they are so often more trouble than they are worth. For this, I'd just use Socket.select in a single thread, or something like that. But  for this, perhaps you could pass the address and port over as uints instead of as part of the Address class. (There's properties on the InternetAddress child class for that, and ditto the constructor). On the receiving end, you have another private instance and call the constructor over it again to reset the values without re-newing it.

Comment: What happens if multiple threads call listen_s.receiveFrom concurrently? If that works you might just run a fixed size pool of workers and have each request be processed in aa single tread.